# How should I fetch user info from Facebook and what database should I use to store user info

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-login, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

so I'm developing an iOS app and I met this problem recently. My app allows user to register with facebook and I want to fetch user information from their facebook account and store them into a user object that I created in my app. So the first question is **how do I fetch user information from Facebook after the user registered with facebook**?

And the second question is I'm planning to use AWS's database service to store my user information in the cloud, but I'm choosing between RDS and DynamoDB, **so I wonder for user information, which would be better?**

Since I have no postgresql or any sql experience I personally think DynamoDB would be easier...Can you guys give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For first question, I think what you're looking for is the graph api?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

If you do some reading up on that you should be able to find your answer or at least narrow your problem down to something more specific.

For your second question, sorry I only have marginal experience with either type of DB, but I think it would depend on the nature of your application.  The limited advice I can give there would be to do a little investigation into the benefits and limitations of relational vs 'noSql' DB models in general, and consider which one fits your use case best.

Comment: I don't think it's the graph api since I just need user info like name, birth date etc. maybe something like FBSession?